# Unable to install any program

Tags: apt, software-installation

Total newbie here, I installed Kubuntu about three days ago and have been trying to install some programmes, to date no success. No matter what I try to install I get the same error. I would be very grateful if someone could explain what is happening and how to resolve it, or point me to a document that can help.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Noel

```
sudo apt-get install muon
[sudo] password for nleric: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 muon : Depends: apt-xapian-index but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

the package "apt-xapian-index" is in the universe repository since Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt-xapian-index). Before Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial the package "apt-xapian-index" was in the main repository, so it was always available, even if the user had the "universe" repository disabled. It's not the case anymore.

To confirm what is above just run the following:

```
apt-cache policy apt-xapian-index
```

If the result is not available it's because apt-get can't find it in the present repositories present in the file /etc/apt/sources.list.

My guess is that you have removed/disabled the universe repository from your APT /etc/apt/sources.list file. Make sure to add "universe" at the end of the the lines starting with "deb" in that file. Example, change the following line to have the universe repository enabled, in the file /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
```

To something like (add the last word in the line):

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
```

Then update apt-get repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Apt-get will update its sources of available packages, now with the universe repository enabled. Then try to fix the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have no idea what you mean here:  Make sure to add "universe" at the end of the the lines starting with "deb" in that file. Then update apt:  I ran the two commands you list above and get this result: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.